# RQDA under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, gtk, r

I try to install RQDA R package under Ubuntu 14.04 which comes with GTK 3 or so. I know that in order to get the RDQA running it needs the GTK 2 development package. I found the following terminal command at the official RQDA webpage (http://rqda.r-forge.r-project.org/) to get the GTK 2 dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

When I run it, the first thing that strikes me is that is asks for around 70 MB more spae to be used and while 25 MB dependency build-up to be downloaded. Secondly, there are errors in download and therefore I cannot proceed to command to install RQDA from within the R: `install.packages("RQDA",dependencies=c("Depends", "Imports"))`.
Obviously, the command shows returns error msg.

Why the GTK 2 dev package needs to install all the dependencies which account up to 70 MB of more space to be used? Can I avoid it? And, how to make RQDA work?
Alternatively, any updated installation instruction for RQDA for 14.04 Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps:

1. In the command-line: `$ sudo apt-get install r-cran-rgtk2 r-cran-cairodevice`
2. In rstudio: `install.packages("RQDA",dependencies=c("Depends", "Imports"))`
3. In rstudio: `library(RQDA)`